# `make menuconfig` overrides configuration with architecture defaults

Tags: kernel, make

I'm cross-compiling a kernel, configuring it with

`$ make sunxi_arm64_defconfig ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-`

which happens to be what I need to do, and then want to make a few adjustments. But running `make menuconfig`, not making any changes, saving and exiting produces a completely different configuration (for starters, the architecture is x86), so I can't use it. Why could that be? Surely, this isn't the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is to apply configuration settings for the current architecture (which *isn’t* the architecture used for the last configuration). When configuring for cross-building, you need to specify the architecture again:

```
make menuconfig ARCH=arm64
```